# Getting callback from class function

Tags: c#, class, delegates

I am trying to figure out how to wait for a callback from a class function (I guess).

My class looks like this:

```
public class DataLogOut
{
    public delegate void OnLogoutResponse(ResponseData data);
    public event OnLogoutResponse onLogoutResponse;

    public static void LogoutPlayer()
    {

        new EndSessionRequest().SetDurable(true).Send((response) => {
            if (!response.HasErrors)
            {

                GS.Reset();

                if (onLogoutResponse != null)
                {
                    onLogoutResponse(new ResponseData()
                    {
                        //data = response
                    });
                }

            }
            else
            {

                if (onLogoutResponse != null)
                {
                    onLogoutResponse(new ResponseData()
                    {
                        errors = response.Errors,
                        hasErrors = response.HasErrors
                    });
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Now I am calling the "LogOutPlayer" like this:

```
public void LogOut()
    {
        DataLogOut.LogoutPlayer();
        DataLogOut.onLogoutResponse += onLogoutResponse;
    }
```

Now i am getting errors in both scripts.
In the first I am getting: Delegate invocation can be simplified

... and in the second script I am not allowed to do this:

```
DataLogOut.onLogoutResponse += onLogoutResponse;
```

Really hop someone can help me with this and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: I'd use [`EventHandler<ResponseData>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler-1?view=netframework-4.8). For the second error, please add more information. What is the error message?

Comment: `onLogoutResponse` is a member variable that's why you are getting the error on statement `DataLogOut.onLogoutResponse`.

Comment: You should also _first_ add the EventHandler, then call the method that will fire the event.

Comment: What @user1672994 is getting at is: `LogoutPlayer` is a static method, while the event `onLogoutResponse` is _not_ static. You'd need an instance of `DataLogOut` to register a handler to that event.

Comment: OK, got me all confused :-) Can you give an example on this... Lost in the woods :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your code. Please see comments:

```
public class DataLogOut
{
    // No need for this, we will use "EventHandler"
    // public delegate void OnLogoutResponse(ResponseData data);

    //public event OnLogoutResponse onLogoutResponse; -> replaced by
    public event EventHandler<ResponseData> onLogoutResponse;

    // Convenience Method to fire the event
    protected virtual void OnLogoutResponse( ResponseData data )
    {
         var handler = onLogoutResponse;
         if( handler != null ){
            handler( this, data );
         }
    }

    // Let's simplify it by making it non-static
    //public static void LogoutPlayer()
    public void LogoutPlayer
    {

        new EndSessionRequest().SetDurable(true).Send((response) => {
            if (!response.HasErrors)
            {

                GS.Reset();

                OnLogoutResponse(new ResponseData()
                {
                   //data = response
                });
            }
            else
            {
                OnLogoutResponse(new ResponseData()
                {
                    errors = response.Errors,
                    hasErrors = response.HasErrors
                });
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void LogOut()
{
    // I made it non-static, so we need an instance ...
    var logout = new DataLogout();
    // first register for the event, then have it fired.
    logout.onLogoutResponse += onLogoutResponse;
    // ^-- You tried to register the handler on the class. Which failed, 
    //     because the event was not static.
    logout.LogoutPlayer();
}

// the handler's signature now must look like this:
public void onLogoutResponse( object sender, ResponseData data ){
   // your code here
}
```

---

If you want to keep it `static`, then make the event static, too:

```
public static event EventHandler<ResponseData> onLogoutResponse;
```

then you need to make the convenience event trigger static, too

```
protected static void OnLogoutResponse( ResponseData data )
    {
         var handler = onLogoutResponse;
         if( handler != null ){
            handler( typeof(DataLogout), data ); // cannot use "this", of course in static context.
         }
    }
```

and then can use it as in your example:

```
public void LogOut()
{
    // first register for the event, then have it fired.
    DataLogout.onLogoutResponse += onLogoutResponse;
    // ^-- You tried to register the handler on the class. Which failed, 
    //     because the event was not static.
    DataLogout.LogoutPlayer();
}

// the handler's signature now must look like this:
public void onLogoutResponse( object sender, ResponseData data ){
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, yes, but... This one gives a red line below: logout.onLogoutResponse += onLogoutResponse; can't figure out why?

Comment: Put your mouse on the red line. What dos it say?

Comment: Ah, I forgot that you need to change the signature of the event handler. Added that to the answer.

Comment: Just one other thing: I chose to go non-static. But that's not really mandatory. You can also make the event static, but then all related stuff has to be static, too. You can also chose to make the above a Singleton if you prefer that.

Comment: THANKS :-) Just what I was aiming for. Great job explaining it for me :-)